# Cannot compile and run Objective C codes on Windows

Tags: objective-c, windows, shell, gnustep

I am new to iOS/Objective C and I am currently trying to set up an environment on my Windows PC to compile and execute Objective C codes.

I googled it and I found that I have to use GNUstep. I already installed it and I created a .mak file and a main.m file in the folder where I work.

Then I opened the shell from GNUstep and change directory to the folder where my files are locate. When I type make, it says: make: *** No targets specified and no make file found. Stop.

I have googled for the error and it says that this error shows that there is no make file. But I have created a make file called GNUmakefile.mak in the directory where the main file is located.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Or Install virtual machine to setup mac os and install xcode.

Comment: People please stop down voting this. ObjectiveC has been around since 1969, a LONG time before the Apple computer company.  The question does not concern cocoa or cocoaTouch libraries nor any Apple platforms

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. You need Xcode on OS X to develop apps for iOS and OS X

Comment: Not exactly true. You may use Visual Studio 2015 on Windows to develop iOS apps (but not in Objective C language).

Comment: I've you need to compile to iOS, like with MonoTouch, you still need a mac to compile.

Comment: For the moment, I just want to practice Objective C.....I read that it is possible to compile and run Objective C codes using GNUstep?

Comment: The question does not mention any apple platforms. ObjectiveC != apple